# Open or closed immersion is separated

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I want to prove the following problem

**Let $Y$ be an open or a closed subscheme of a scheme $X$, with the natural inclusion $i:Y \hookrightarrow X $. Prove that $Y$ is separated over $X$.**

I don't understand what the role of "**open or close subscheme**" is here? Does it represent "open or closed immersion".

If that's the case, then the problem can be reduced to what I mentioned in my title.

(This "separated" means: Let $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism between scheme $X$ and scheme $Y$. If the diagonal morphism $\Delta(X):X \to X\times_Y X$ is closed, then we call $f$ is **separated**)

Please give me some hints, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically, this follows from the fact that the intersection of an open/closed subscheme with itself is the subscheme itself again. In a general category with the necessary limits, the following holds: a morphism $g\colon Y\to X$ is a monomorphism iff the commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>{\mathrm{id}}>> Y\\
@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @VV{g}V\\
Y @>{g}>> X
\end{CD}$$
is a pullback diagram in this category. (Edit: This is the case iff the diagonal $\Delta\colon Y\to Y\times_X Y$ is an isomorphism.) In particular, any monomorphism of schemes is separated, so you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't understand how "any monomorphism of schemes is separated" was obtained. Why is the image of $Y\to Y\times_X Y$ closed?

Comment: Since $Y$ is a pullback of $Y\xrightarrow{g} X\xleftarrow{g} Y$, the diagonal $\Delta\colon Y\to Y\times_X Y$ is an isomorphism. This follows from uniqueness of pullbacks: the square above is commutative so induces a map $Y\to Y\times_X Y$, and looking at the left vertical and upper horizontal map, this map will be the diagonal. But $Y$ itself is also a pullback of the square, so this map has to be an isomorphism.

Comment: I understand. Thankyou！

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. I have two questions about sheaves. Could you please help me answer them？

Comment: @ym2333 I can definitely try. Which questions are they?

Comment: Thank you very much! They are these two questions     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838515/the-canonical-sheaf-of-hypersurface-on-mathbbpn   and    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839770/the-kunneth-formula-for-cohomology-of-quasi-coherent-sheaves-on-varieties