# The canonical sheaf of hypersurface on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-varieties, line-bundles

I want to prove the following result

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth projective variety defined over $k.$ Let $Y= V(f)$ be a smooth subvariety of $X$ defined by a homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d.$ Show that

$$
\omega_Y=i^*(\omega_X\otimes\mathscr{O}_X(d)),
$$

where $i:Y\to X$ is the inclusion, $i^*$ is the pull-back of $i$, $\omega_Y$ is the canonical sheaf of Y, $\mathscr{O}_X(d)=i^{'*}\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)$, $i': X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is the inclusion.

I think of using the following exact sequences

$$
0\to\mathscr{O}_X(-d)\to i'^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to\Omega_X\to0
$$
or
$$
0\to\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2\to\Omega_X\otimes\mathscr{O}_Y\to\Omega_Y\to0
$$

And I think of **adjunction formula $\omega_Y\cong\omega_X\otimes\wedge^r (\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2)^*$**(by Hartshorne II 8.20), where $(\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2)^* = Hom_{\mathscr{O}_Y}(\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2,\mathscr{O}_Y)$.

I want to imitate the proof of this result, but I don't understand this proof.

Perhaps this direction is wrong. Anyway, please give me some hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, the adjunction formula says
$$\omega_X\simeq i^*\omega_{\mathbb P^n}\otimes(\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2)^\vee,$$
so it suffices to check the isomorphism of $\mathcal O_X$-modules
$$\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2\simeq \mathcal O_X(-d).$$
Recall that $\mathcal O_X$-modules are (essentially) equivalent to graded modules over the graded ring $S=k[x_0,\dots,x_n]/(f)$, with grading:
$$S_{(e)}=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e)}/fk[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-d)}.$$
Now, $\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2$ corresponds to the graded module
$$I/I^2=\bigoplus_{e\ge0}fk[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-d)}/f^2k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-2d)}.$$
On the other hand, $\mathcal O_X(-d)$ is just the Serre twist, corresponding to the graded module
$$S(-d)=\bigoplus_{e\ge0}S_{(e-d)}=\bigoplus_{e\ge0}k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-d)}/fk[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-2d)}.$$
There is now an obvious isomorphism of graded $S$-modules
$$\begin{align*}
m_f\colon S(-d)&\xrightarrow\sim I/I^2\\
x\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-d)}/fk[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-2d)}&\mapsto fx\in fk[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-d)}/f^2k[x_1,\dots,x_n]_{(e-2d)}.
\end{align*}$$
given by multiplication by $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't understand how $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2\simeq\mathcal{O}_X(-d)$ was obtained (I understand $I\simeq\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-d)$). And if we need to prove this problem by adjunction formula , we have $i^*\omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(d) = i^*(\omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(d))$, but how is this proven? Is it the definition of $i^*$?

Comment: $\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2\simeq\mathcal I\otimes_{\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}}\mathcal O_X$. Also note that $\mathcal O_X(d)$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, so it doesn't even strictly make sense to write $\omega_{\mathbb P^n}\otimes\mathcal O_X(d)$. So what I write is the correct statement of the adjunction formula.

Comment: Sorry, I suddenly realized that I made a mistake because of adjunction formula $\omega_Y\cong\omega_X\otimes\wedge^r(\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2)^{\vee}$, so I should prove $i^*(\omega_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(d)) = i^*\omega_X\otimes\wedge^r\mathcal{O}_{X}(d)$. I don't know if this is correct or not. Anyway, thank you again for your answer.

Comment: I have another question about this proposition: May I ask how $\omega_Y\simeq i^*\omega_X\otimes(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)^\vee$ was obtained from $\omega_Y\cong\omega_X\otimes\wedge^r(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)^{\vee}$.